# Как получить список id всех пользовотелей групы в Телеграме, в которой есть бот

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Как получить список id всех пользовотелей групы в Телеграме, в которой есть бот питон  pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: [возможные дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=telegram+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85)

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя найти id пользователя если он не чего не сделал в чате

Comment: это разве ответ на вопрос?